# How to set classpath in manifest file , while creating JAR from eclipse?

Tags: java, jar, manifest, executable-jar

```
I am trying to creat JAR file through eclipse. I read some of the threads from
```

stackoverflow as well as other forums. But nothing is helping.

I have created a separate manifest file like this one.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: Main
Class-Path: gnujaxp.jar iText-2.1.5.jar jcalendar.jar jcommon-1.0.16.jar jfreechart-1.0.13.jar jfreechart-1.0.13-experimental.jar jfreechart-1.0.13-swt.jar junit.jar servlet.jar swtgraphics2d.jar tinyos.jar
```

I have put all this jars in same project folder.

While exporting i am exporting all resources (meants this jar files also.)

But still i am getting noclassdeffound error when my application tries to load any one of the jar included.

M i wrong anywhere ..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using eclipse >=3.4 try "export as runnable jar file" it should generate it correctly.

Otherwhise you can provide your own manifest file in the export as jar dialog.

Answer (score 2):

I get this error and find that my `manifest` needs a space after the jars in the `class-path`. This includes the ones at the end of the line and end of list, otherwise it mashes them together.

Comment: Underrated response. If you are putting each jar on it's own line, each line must start with a space AND end with a space. You would assume that starting with a space would cover it but because that space is required for the file format, it is not included in the final concatenation of all of the jars, leading to one mashed up line like you said.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to add an empty line at the end of your Manifest file.