# com.mysql.jdbc.Driver Error when I run the Jar File although that exists in my Build Path

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jdbc, jar

I have created a java swing application with rmi and export als Jar File the Client.Althout that my Jar File is runing with the first mySql connection comming the following Error Message. Everything works perfect when I compile and run the program in Eclipse, the Error comes only as a Jar file. So far I have searched here and generell, have seen that the problem has with my Build Path to do, althougth that the mysql-connecor-java-5.1.37-bin.jar inlcuded in Build Path and in the classpath.

The Error message:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at util.ConnectDB.getConnection(ConnectDB.java:14)
    at clientValantis.LoginForm.<init>(LoginForm.java:59)
    at clientValantis.Main$1.run(Main.java:16)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source) java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at util.ConnectDB.getConnection(ConnectDB.java:14)
    at clientValantis.LoginForm.<init>(LoginForm.java:59)
    at clientValantis.LoginForm$1.run(LoginForm.java:41)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

then my Build Path is like this :
[image]

have to inlcude more jar into my build path pr what I m doing wrong when I export the Jar File and comes this Error. I m doint it in Eclipse 
Export -> JAR file -> Select the destination -> Generate the manifest file ->Select the Main class -> Finish

and here my classpath
[image]

The MANIFEST.MF that generated from Eclipse only has this inside

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0 Main-Class: clientValantis.Main
```

Comment: why 2 jars of Mysql Connector ?

Comment: @RafikBELDI And 3 junit.jar files, and other duplicates...

Comment: Your problem is with the *runtime* classpath, not the build path. What classpath do you specify when running the .jar file? If running with `-jar`, what classpath is listed in the MANIFEST.MF file?

Comment: @Andreas yes its running with the -jar if I understand good the wuestion. Have also the classpath in my question included and in my Manifest.mf  I don do anything what from Eclipse is generated

Comment: So show the content of the generated manifest file. Confirm that it lists the mysql.jar file, and that the file actually exists.

Comment: @Andreas I shoed also the MANIFEST at my question, generates only this two lines

Comment: Then the runtime classpath is just your .jar file when running using `-jar`. Either change the build to define the classpath in the manifest file, or run using `java -cp myjar.jar;mysql.jar;...all the other jars... clientValantis.Main`.

Comment: @Andreas Thank you very much but can you please describe me with more details -first time with jar files- how can I change the build to define the classpath in the manifest file ? cause after that want to use the launch4j dont want to run it manually with all this values and jars java  -cp myjar.jar.....

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2636078/how-to-set-classpath-in-manifest-file-while-creating-jar-from-eclipse